# Click Tab, Tabs Disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Creating tabs in jQuery.  When you click another tab, all the tabs disappear.  Can't figure out the fix

Here's the page not working: http://www.sleepfullnights.com/products/sfn-537

Here's the JSFiddle another guy made of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/gravitybox/7pHg4/  I've copied and pasted every element of this into the page and the issue is still there.

One person pointed out that something is giving the tabs the css "display:none" when clicked and I can't find where to fix it.

Also, another observation someone made was that "In Chrome dev tools, if you right click the ul.tabs in the "Elements" tab and select "Break On > Attributes modifications", it breaks on "$(contentLocation).show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('act‌​ive');" when you click a tab".

Here's the jQuery code I have:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
      var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
      active = links.first().addClass('active');
      content = $(active.attr('href'));
      links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
      });
      $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
        active.removeClass('active');
        content.hide();
        active = $(this);
        content = $($(this).attr('href'));
        active.addClass('active');
        content.show();
        return false;
      });
    });
  });
```

And the code from the working JSFiddle:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('ul.tabs').each(function(){
  var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
  active = links.first().addClass('active');
  content = $(active.attr('href'));
  links.not(':first').each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();

  });
  $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
    active.removeClass('active');
    content.hide();
    active = $(this);
    content = $($(this).attr('href'));
    active.addClass('active');
    content.show();
    return false;
      alert('yep');
  });
});
});
```

Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the one who noted "In Chrome dev tools, if you right click the ul.tabs in the "Elements" tab and select "Break On > Attributes modifications", it breaks on "$(contentLocation).show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('act‌​ive');"

It breaks there because that line is what is hiding the `ul` containing the tabs.

Looking at your website's code, you need to change the following inside `app.js` on Line 39.

```
$(contentLocation).show().addClass('active').siblings().hide().removeClass('active');
```

to this:

```
$(contentLocation).show().addClass('active').siblings('div').hide().removeClass('active');
```

You only want to target the `div` siblings of the selected tab's content `div`. Right now, the `ul` is also a sibling of the selected `div`. Without the `'div'`, `siblings()` will select all of its siblings and `hide()` them (thus hiding the tabs too).

Preferably, I would add a `tab-content` class to the tab content `div` elements and use `siblings('.tab-content')` instead of `siblings('div')` to be more specific. That way if you add another `div` that happens to be a sibling, it won't hide that.

Comment: You are the MAN!!!!! Thank you this worked perfectly! I would never have found that on my own.  Thank you so much.  If I had enough reputation, I would upvote your answer with an overly enthusiastic click.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad it resolved your issue!

Comment: Spot on, very nice! +1

Answer (score 2):

## What's Going On

The code used for those tabs is much more complicated than you need, and I'm not really sure what is breaking. Rather than try to fix it, it would be easier to just start over. This is what you want:

Every time a user clicks on a tab, all tabs have the `active` class removed, and all content is hidden. Then, the active clicked on tab is given the `active` class and it's content is shown. This should seem instantaneous to the user. You will need to add a class to your content `div`s to accomplish this easily. I'd add `tab-content`.

## Code

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XZ2A/1/)

#### HTML (Only change is adding the class)

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-1">
    ...Content...
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-2">
    ...Content...
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="tab-3">
    ...Content...
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tabs li a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.tabs li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.tab-content').hide();
        $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    });

});
```

Comment: I copied and pasted in the exact code from the fiddle you put up and it's not working.  Is it possible the active instruction is being overridden by something elsewhere on the site?

Comment: Was able to solve it with a combination of your code plus adjusting something in the app.js page.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet. otherwise I absolutely would.  Once I get past 15 I'll try to come back and throw you the upvote you deserve

Comment: No problem, I should have remembered that limit seeing your points. Just remember to give Sombre one as well if you do come back. I see lots of people upvote all good answers EXCEPT the one they give the checkmark, which is silly! :D Cheers on an interesting question, and I'm glad it's solved.

Comment: I'm a real person now. Upvote delivered.  Cheers and thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a problem with the `ul` getting `display: none`. You could try overriding it in the click handler with `$('ul.tabs').css('display','block')`. It's hard to tell where the issues is coming from because of the amount of scripts on your page.

Comment: Was able to get it squared away with some crazy app.js stuff I never would have found on my own.  Thanks so much for helping guide me through this process.  Cheers